# How to return to Iron Router route after login when login is clicked and a different route?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

In my app a user can navigate around anonymously without logging in. There is a dropdown to log in from any anonymous-friendly route.  The dropdown has a link to a separate `loginPage` route and thus changes the route when clicked using `Render.go('loginPage')`.  I'm trying to figure out how to return the user to the previous page they were on after logging in.

I understand the typical `onBeforeAction(requireLogin)...` method and that works if a page **requires** a login to access it.  It re-evaluates `Meteor.user()` and then calls `this.next()`.

My issue is when a user **clicks** to log in and they're taken to the `loginPage` route, how to then get them back to the previous page.  I was trying to call something like `Router.render('loginPage')` in the click event but you can't call `Router.render()` on the client like how you can inside a route. Apparently only `Router.go()` works on the client, thus changing the route.

The only way I can think of is to have every anonymous-friendly route in my app have an `onBeforeAction` that tests for a `Session` variable (e.g. `loginRequested`).  If the user clicks on "Sign In", it sets `loginRequested` which would invalidate the route. Once they sign in I would clear `loginRequested` and then the `onBeforeAction` would call `this.next()` taking them back to the previous page.  This would work unless the user hits "Back" in their browser.  I would have to listen for that and clear `loginRequested` so the route would validate. Is there a way to do that in Iron Router?

This just seems really hacky.  Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:  I forgot to mention that my `loginPage` route actually has its own `action:` if the user goes directly to the login page through the URL it will forward them to a specific route.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `history.back();` after a successful log in.

E.g:

```
Router.route('/login', {
    onBeforeAction: function(){
        // Do logging stuff
        history.back();
    }
});
```

Iron Router is kind of hacky itself, so if you decide to handle logging in the route, you might have to call `this.next()` somewhere.

Comment: So I forgot to mention that my `loginRoute` actually has its own action.  So if the user goes directly to `http://appurl.com/login` the `loginPage` route's `action:` does `Router.go('defaultRoute')`. So doing an `onBeforeAction` with `history.back()` once they're logged in actually kills the `action:` if they go directly to the `loginRoute` - it just hangs and does nothing.  I may need to figure out a way to detect a `history` and if there is history then call `history.back()` else call `this.next()` which would fire the `action:`.

Comment: It looks like doing a little history test, at least in Firefox, does the trick.  In the `onBeforeAction` of the `loginRoute`, after logging in I'm testing if `document.referrer == ""`, if so, I call `this.next()` which fires the `loginRoute`'s default action, if not, I call `history.back()`.

Comment: So I've done continued testing and using `history.back()` is definitely not a good solution - at least not a very robust one.  I've noticed that if anyone hits one of my app's pages after navigating from an outside page, once they log in, `history.back()` sends the back out to the outside site.  There's just too many edge cases for this to work.  AND I figured out a real solution.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the best way to solve my above problem is indeed through the use of Session variables.  Something like:

```
if(!Meteor.user()) {
    if(Session.get('wantsToLogIn`) == null)
        this.next();
    else
        this.render('loginPage');
}
else
   this.next();
```

So if a user is on some page and decides to log in, you just set a Session variable `wantsToLogin`.  If you set it, it invalidates the `onBeforeAction` and evaluates to call `this.render('loginPage')`, once the user logs in the `onBeforeAction` again invalidates and listens for `Meteor.user()`, and as soon as the user is logged in the `onBeforeAction` calls `this.next()`.  Basically everything I said in my question... I don't know why I didn't just do that to begin with.